# selecting adjacent elements in CSS

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors

In CSS,

Is it possible to match the elements which have a certain property followed by an element which has another property, ie.

Let's consider

```
<div my-custom-attribute="0">
</div>

<div my-custom-attribute="1">
</div>
```

I want to select all elements which have my-custom-attribute equal 0 that are followed by elements which have my-custom-attribute equals 1

Comment: Previous sibling selectors do not exist yet, so it's not possible with the existing selectors.

Comment: I ended up doing this with Javascript with jQuery. Thank you

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it. You might help future visitors who stumble onto your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in reverse order by attribute selectors

```
div[my-custom-attribute="0"] > div[my-custom-attribute="1"]
```

or

```
<div id="parent">
    <div my-custom-attribute="0">
    </div>
    <div my-custom-attribute="1">
    </div>
</div>

#parent > div[my-custom-attribute]:not(:first-child)
```

Comment: `>` is a child selector, which won't do anything useful. The second method does not deal with the values of `my-custom-attribute`, but its relative position among its siblings.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want :

```
div[my-custom-attribute="0"] + div[my-custom-attribute="1"] { 
  color:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/uximuj/2/edit)

Refer to this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) for more info on selectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since each div can have children, this solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I ended up using jQuery selectors instead of CSS.

For my case, the jQuery `prev()` worked

```
$($('div[my-custom-attribute="1"]').prev('div[my-custom-attribute="0"]'))
```